# Question on an example of Reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

We restrict our attention to the case where $H$ is a Hilbert space of real valued functions define on some set $E$.

Let $H$ be a finite-dimensional Hilbert space with $\{ e_1,...,e_p\} $ an associated orthonormal basis. Now define

$$K(s,t)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^p e_i(s) e_i(t)$$

for $s,t \in E$. Clearly, $K(\cdot,t) \in H$. Also, for $1 \leq j \leq p$,

$$\langle e_j, K(\cdot,t) \rangle=    \sum\limits_{i=1}^p  \langle e_j, e_i  \rangle e_i (t)=e_j(t) $$

from which the reproducing property follows at once. Thus, $H$ is an RKHS.

My question: How to get the step $$\langle e_j, K(\cdot,t) \rangle=    \sum\limits_{i=1}^p  \langle e_j, e_i  \rangle e_i (t)=e_j(t) $$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s,t\in E$. As

$$ K(s,t) = \sum_{i=1}^{p}e_{i}(t)e_{i}(s) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{p}e_{i}(t)e_{i} \right)(s), $$

it follows that

$$ K(\cdot , t) = \sum_{i=1}^{p}e_{i}(t)e_{i}.$$

From the conjugate linearity of the second entry of the inner product, if $j \in \{1, \ldots , p\}$,
\begin{align*}
\langle e_{j}, K(\cdot ,t) \rangle &= \left\langle e_{j}, \sum_{i=1}^{p}e_{i}(t)e_{i} \right\rangle \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^{p}\langle e_{j}, e_{i} \rangle e_{i}(t).
\end{align*}
This obtains the desired result.